# How can I duplicate UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios5

I have a UIPageControl that allows the user to swipe between several UITableView.
I have designed my table view in the StoryBoard then I hooked it up in my code.
The problem is, these table views will not have the same number of rows.
So, I would like to know how can I make a copy of the table view I made in StoryBoard to keep its design.

I already try that:

```
// self.theTableView is the tableview made in StoryBoard
UITableView *myTableView = self.theTableView;

NSData *tmpArchive = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: myTableView];
UITableView *newTableView = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectWithData:tmpArchive];
```

The problem is that I have multiple tableviews but all have the same number of rows (I think that in fact is the same tableview in memory and I don't want that).

In a nutshell, I want to make copy of my table view made in Storyboard to keep its style.

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0):

if you need to add two tableviews inside a controller you should have give them two different names and check for the same in the delegate & datasource methods and do whatever you want inside the conditions.